# How to solve .net framework System.InvalidProgramException error

Tags: .net

I was getting this error while trying to run basic flasher tool.
I have attached screenshots below. 
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkCRg.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqduO.png)

Comment: Are you working with Crystal Report?-@yash

Comment: See if you can get hold of fresh copies of the assemblies you reference, "Invalid program" means something is corrupt.

Comment: No Sir,I am not working with Crystal Report -@SanjayKumaar

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN - InvalidProgramException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidprogramexception.aspx)

Also try upgrading .NET Framework to a newer version if you are using  4.5.1.